# Python: Space floats in long string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am producing a large output file, which goes over several lines. This is a shortened version of a section I hope to produce.

```
line = \
f"""
Output: {a} {b:0.10f} {c:0.8f}
"""
```

where a, b, and c are floats of variable length.

In the example above, I have managed to shorten the b float and c float to 10 decimal places and 8 decimal places respectively.

However, I am hoping to get a string which when printed looks like:

```
Output: 10.05     0.0987654321           0.87654321
```

Where the spacing between the values can be controlled individually and is not necessarily equal. Essentially, I hope to lock the values in position.
This is made difficult by the fact that `a` could also be a tuple of varying length (which impacts the positioning of the floats).

Is this possible without the `.format()` method?
If not, how should the `.format()` method be used correctly?

Comment: Do you mean https://pyformat.info/#number_padding…?

Comment: Hi @deceze. That is a really useful link; however, I'm a bit confused how I can do both floats and spaces at the same time. Kind of in the `{b:6.2f:4d} way?

Comment: E.g.: `'{b:20.10f}'` — format with 10 decimal places to a total length of 20 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the space before the specifier and drop the `0` prefix for the float

The value before the `.` is the padding and position, and not necessarily the 0-prefix for a float

```py
>>> f"Output: {a} {b:.10f} {c:.8f}"
'Output: 10.05 0.0987654321  0.87654321'
>>> f"Output: {a: <5} {b: >15.10f} {c:0>15.8f}"
'Output: 10.05    0.0987654321 000000.87654321'
```

Comment: Thank you @ti7. I was wondering about that same but if the a is a tuple of varying length, but still lock the numbers in the same position.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Wychh Most any time! if this solved your Question, please mark it as the Answer with the check to its left!